# Error running pg_basebackup

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf

I'm running Postgres16 on Windows server.
Start researching on pg_basebackup - when I execute the following command, `pg_basebackup.exe -h SERVERNAME -U postgres -p 5432 -D Z:\PostgreSQL\16\backups\ -Fp -Xs -P -R --checkpoint=fast --max-rate=1024M`
I'm getting the following error:

> pg_basebackup: error: connection to server at "servername" port 5432
> failed: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from
> host, user "postgres", no encryption

I think it's because I added the [SSPI connections](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/334070/postgresql-sspi-error-connection-failed-1-port-5432-failed-fe-sendauth-no/334082#334082).

I have the following entries before the sspi but still getting error

```
host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0       scram-sha-256 
host    all     all     127.0.0.1/32    scram-sha-256 
host    all     all     ::0/0           sspi    map=sspi
```

How do I fix pg_hba so I can use sspi for certain usernames will able to allow connections for local logins (much like mixed mode in MSSQL)?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic database name "all" does not match the magic database name "replication" used for replication connections, so there is no match in your pg_hba.  You could use "all,replication" if you want to include replication connections in your existing pg_hba configuration without repeating yourself.

Comment: Thank you jjanes for the suggestions. I added "replication" to the host all,replication  all  0.0.0.0/0  scram-sha-256
host    all,replication         all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256 , restarted service but still getting similar error.

Comment: For future reference, make sure you have "all,replication" on the user that is running the pg_basebackup. In my case, I was using an AD service account, so I had to add "all,replication" to the sspi in pg_hba.conf